# Getting results prioritized by a specific column value - ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
Rails 3.2
```

I know how to use the .order method to get results using ActiveRecord, but I am stuck on doing the equivalent of :

```
SELECT * from product ORDER BY case when status = 'new'
```

with ActiveRecord. I tried different combinations of the syntax to no avail, and there are no examples as far as I can tell in the ActiveRecord API guide. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to order with a `CASE` conditional. In Rails, you have to include the entire `CASE` in the call to `order`, e.g.

```
Product.order("CASE status WHEN 'new' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END")
```

Comment: I think this is working for me now. I have another one where solr is used. For solr, it would be order_by and it looks like I cannot do something like this with solr, but I I will post it as another question.